# How do I get up quicker in the morning?

Tags: personal-care

If I am tired, I don't want to get up.

---

What are a few tips for getting up quicker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tips for getting out of bed quicker in the mornings?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/18669/tips-for-getting-out-of-bed-quicker-in-the-mornings)

Answer (score 5):

If it's cold in your room, throw all the blankets on the floor at the foot of the bed. Then you'll be miserable lying there, and you'll be a lot more likely to get up - if only to get into a warm shower or put on a robe!

Answer (score 5):

You live in the 21st century. Get an annoying alarm app and **charge your phone out of reach of your bed**. Natural light alarms and Bollywood dance numbers are good choices.

---

## [If you're a traditionalist](http://mentalfloss.com/article/24117/7-ways-people-woke-pre-alarm-clock):

- **Drink more before you sleep**. Waking up with a full bladder very quickly wakes you the rest of the way up.
- **Move to a country with muezzin**. (Those would be the ones that self-identify as 'Islamic'.) The first of the five calls to prayer happens at dawn, and the loudspeakers can be obnoxious.
- **Move to a country with obnoxious vegetable vendors**. (That would be India, where sabziwaalas have taken it upon themselves to replace the old muezzins.)
  [image]
- **Hire a knocker-upper**. ([The British English kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knocker-up), not the American one.) Have someone bigger than you are come by and keep making noise on your walls, doors, and windows until you get the f' up.
- **[The American version can work, too](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/sex-love/news/a47650/why-is-your-boyfriend-always-waking-up-with-morning-wood/)**...
- **Get a rice cooker** or something else with a built-in timer, so you have something warm and delicious waiting for you in the kitchen at wake o'clock.
- [**Get a cat**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crepuscular_animal). Then get another one from a different place. They're matutinal and crepuscular hunters (i.e., they sleep while you're at work but are frisky once you get home and at 5 AM EVERY GODDAMN MORNING WTF YOUR BOWLS ARE FULL GODDAMMIT... Oh, I'm awake...).

---

## If you're sensible,

though, it's easier to just listen to yourself.

> If I am tired, I don't want to get up.

**Go to bed earlier and get better quality sleep** by avoiding caffeine and screens for the hour plus before that; by using curtains, blinds, or blindfolds to darken your room; block, cover, or turn any small lights, like from laptop charging cords and power strips; and by using soundproofing, earplugs, or white noise (fans, ACs, YouTube videos of fans and ACs, &c.), avoiding sudden noises interrupting your sleep. Using your TV/computer/phoneless hour or so for a walk or having done cardio earlier in the day also helps.

Answer (score 3):

### Set up two alarm clocks

If you use your phone to wake up, you can set one alarm at the exact time to wake up, and another 15 mins earlier. The first will awake you, but you *know* you've still got an extra quarter hour to crawl in your warm bed.
And even if you fall asleep again, the next alarm will wake you up better disposed than one alarm only would have.

I use this trick on a daily basis (working days only though) and it works great. I wouldn't recommend setting your alarms more than 20, 30 max minutes apart though, because falling asleep between the alarms you would get in a deep sleep state and you wouldn't wake up fresh enough.

Comment: That can make the person sleeping next to you grumpy, though. They might not mind your alarm if you get up at once, but if you just go back to sleep in anticipation of the second alarm, they think the first alarm woke them up for nothing.

Comment: @Lawrence true, it annoyed my wife at first, so I explained the trick to her. Now she's used to it and won't even wake up anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I learned this in sixth grade (a **very** long time ago) and it actually works and doesn't require self torture to do.

While dozing in your bed, with your eyes closed and still snuggled warmly in the blankets, simply begin by consciously moving one finger back an forth a few times.  Then stop and move the next finger back and forth a few times.  Continue with all the fingers on one hand, them move all the fingers on that hand.  Next, move on to the other hand in the exact same manner - i.e., one finger at a time, then all the fingers at the same time.  Then wiggle all your fingers on both hands at the same time.

If you aren't fully awake by this time, simply move on to your toes, doing everything listed above.  You can do fingers and toes together, then add wrists and ankles, etc.  The key is that you're using your brain to activate various body parts into physical motion.

I **GUARANTEE** that after doing all of the above, even if your eyes are still closed, you will be fully awake.  It's painless, comfortable, soundless, and it works perfectly every time.

You're welcome.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Starting this thread with fun!
Watch Kramer from Seinfeld trying the polyphasic sleep schedule, [but it didn’t work out well for him](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XLTg2nHZEHQ)

Note: This answer is no way a promotional / influencing religious message

I remember when I was a kid, and my dad used to teach us the benefits of getting up early and begin the day with a positive value that you want to practice that day!

Our day used to start with something like the following article and if someone wishes to give a try! Which has been time-tested by several yogis for generations!. http://www.sanatansociety.org/ayurveda_home_remedies/ayurveda_glory_waking_up.htm#.W0LBT6czbnY

The short version,

- Get a sufficient amount of sleep
- Practice waking up to a mental alarm if you can!
- Immediately wake up to alarm, Sit up straight in bed
- Observe the way you breathe with eyes closed for a min
- Open your eyes looking at both of your palms! And close your eyes.
- Rub both palms together vigorously, once they are warm massage your face in a circular motion, massage eyelids with the forefinger, eyebrows hold them in pinching action with hands with gentle press and releases. Continue this for at least 2 mins
- Open your eyes now and look at the natural light if can.
- Get on with your daily chores and exercise routines.

You will never feel sleepy after waking like this and with practice comes stronger will to cherish early mornings.

Understand modern-day impediments that prevent you to get up early:

- No ways for natural light to enter bedrooms, waking up to nature is bliss.
- Sleeping late hooked to entertainment routines
- Bad eating/drinking habits before sleep
- Not watching sleeping posture etc